# Effect of OrderBy on Group-By Items

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, group-by, sql-order-by

Given a query similar to the following:

```
var results = from x in context.Table
              orderby x.SortOrder
              group x by x.GroupColumn into g
              select g;
```

Is there any guarantee that items within each group will also be sorted by `SortOrder`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, group by guarantees order of source IEnumerable. See [this.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534304.aspx)

> Elements in a grouping are yielded in the order that the elements that produced them appear in source.